# How can I put Kendo controls in a Partial View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-autocomplete

I'm putting a Kendo Tabstrip in one of the areas in my C# MVC project.

```
<div id="tabstrip">
<ul>
    <li class="k-state-active">
        Teachers
    </li>
    <li>
        Students
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="teachers">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("Teachers"); }
</div>
<div id="students">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("Students"); }
</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, there are just two tabs and I'm putting their contents in partial views.

The problem is, I want to put more Kendo controls in those partial views. I want both tabs to have a Kendo Grid, AutoComplete widgets, and so on. So, I put the following code in Teachers.cshtml:

```
<input id="products" style="width: 250px" />

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var data = { "foo": ["item 1", "test 2", "item 3"] };
        $("#products").kendoAutoComplete({
            filter: "contains",
            minLength: 2,
            dataSource: {
                data: data,
                schema: {
                    data: "foo"
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is just a standard AutoComplete widget. It works fine when I just put it in one of the tabs, but if I try to put that same code in both tabs, it doesn't work. The `input` field on the first tab becomes as wide as the screen, and no suggestions show up when I type stuff in on the second tab.

I don't really know how else to do this. How do I put Kendo controls in a Tabstrip using Partial Views?

Comment: Do they have different IDs on each tab? Or is it `#products` on both tabs? That could be your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, both widgets have the same ID. I changed the ID in the second tab and it works fine.